# How to change a 2d array from dynamic to static of a specific size?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, static, 2d

I currently have the dynamic array:

```
char *myData[500][10]; //myData is the name of an array of[500][10] pointers to type char.
```

I would like to create a static 2d array, 500 rows X 10 columns, each element storing memory for 40 characters.

Would below be the correct way of declaring that?

```
char myData[500][10][40];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

*But*:

- This is a large structure, and declaring it on the stack may not be a good idea
- This approach has less flexibility that the dynamic version
- if you mean to use NULL terminated strings with up to 40 characters of data, you should use `[500][10][41]` to leave room for the `\0`